# filter/select rows of pandas dataframe by timestamp column

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I am new to pandas. I have dataframe with two columns dt (date-time stamp) and value.

Given two start and end data-time stamps: is there a easy way to create a new dataframe from original one that contains rows between the two date-time stamp?

```
                dt    value
84    7/23/2014 7:00  0.300
85    7/23/2014 7:05  0.300
86    7/23/2014 7:10  0.312
87    7/23/2014 7:15  0.300
88    7/23/2014 7:20  0.300
89    7/23/2014 7:25  0.300
90    7/23/2014 7:30  0.300
91    7/23/2014 7:35  0.300
92    7/23/2014 7:40  0.300
93    7/23/2014 7:45  0.216
94    7/23/2014 7:50  0.204
95    7/23/2014 7:55  0.228
96    7/23/2014 8:00  0.228
97    7/23/2014 8:05  0.228
98    7/23/2014 8:10  0.228
99    7/23/2014 8:15  0.240
100   7/23/2014 8:20  0.228
101   7/23/2014 8:25  0.216
102   7/23/2014 8:30  0.228
103   7/23/2014 8:35  0.324
104   7/23/2014 8:40  0.336
105   7/23/2014 8:45  0.324
106   7/23/2014 8:50  0.324
107   7/23/2014 8:55  0.324
108   7/23/2014 9:00  0.252
109   7/23/2014 9:05  0.252
110   7/23/2014 9:10  0.240
111   7/23/2014 9:15  0.240
112   7/23/2014 9:20  0.252
113   7/23/2014 9:25  0.240
..               ...    ...
198  7/23/2014 16:30  0.132
199  7/23/2014 16:35  0.120
200  7/23/2014 16:40  0.180
201  7/23/2014 16:45  0.216
202  7/23/2014 16:50  0.204
203  7/23/2014 16:55  0.192
```

Answer (score 68):

So long as dt is a datetime dtype already you can filter using date strings, if not then you can convert doing this:

```
df['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dt'])
```

Then filter:

```
In [115]:

df[(df['dt'] > '2014-07-23 07:30:00') & (df['dt'] < '2014-07-23 09:00:00')]
Out[115]:
                       dt  value
index                           
91    2014-07-23 07:35:00  0.300
92    2014-07-23 07:40:00  0.300
93    2014-07-23 07:45:00  0.216
94    2014-07-23 07:50:00  0.204
95    2014-07-23 07:55:00  0.228
96    2014-07-23 08:00:00  0.228
97    2014-07-23 08:05:00  0.228
98    2014-07-23 08:10:00  0.228
99    2014-07-23 08:15:00  0.240
100   2014-07-23 08:20:00  0.228
101   2014-07-23 08:25:00  0.216
102   2014-07-23 08:30:00  0.228
103   2014-07-23 08:35:00  0.324
104   2014-07-23 08:40:00  0.336
105   2014-07-23 08:45:00  0.324
106   2014-07-23 08:50:00  0.324
107   2014-07-23 08:55:00  0.324
```

Answer (score 8):

You can also use [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
In [25]: df.query('"2014-07-23 07:55:00" <= dt <= "2014-07-23 08:20:00"')
Out[25]: 
                     dt  value
95  2014-07-23 07:55:00  0.228
96  2014-07-23 08:00:00  0.228
97  2014-07-23 08:05:00  0.228
98  2014-07-23 08:10:00  0.228
99  2014-07-23 08:15:00  0.240
100 2014-07-23 08:20:00  0.228
```

Comment: I got a small problem : "Cannot compare tz-naive and tz-aware datetime-like objects" but i solved it by the following : df.query('"2023-04-01 00:00:00.000Z" <= dt < "2024-10-01 00:00:00.000Z"').

Answer (score 6):

The answer above is right, but for people who just like me stumble upon this question more than 5 years after it was posted I want to add this remark.

If you want to filter on a sorted column (and timestamps tend to be like one) it is more efficient to use the [searchsorted](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.searchsorted.html) function of pandas Series to reach O(log(n)) complexity instead of O(n).

The example below gives as a result in a difference of much more than a factor 1000. This difference can be made arbitrarily large due to the difference in complexity off course, but the chosen numbers are the ones I was using when I stumbled upon this question.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import timeit

N = 500000
M = 200

data = np.hstack([np.arange(0.,N).reshape(N,1),np.random.randn(N,M-1)])
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=["column"+str(i) for i in range(M)])

def return_first(df):
    return df[(df['column0'] > 100.5) & (df['column0'] < 400000.5)]

def return_second(df):
    t1 = df['column0'].searchsorted(100.5)
    t2 = df['column0'].searchsorted(400000.5)
    return df.loc[t1:t2-1]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = timeit.timeit(lambda: return_first(df), number=100)
    print(t)
    t = timeit.timeit(lambda: return_second(df), number=100)
    print(t)
```

results:

```
59.1751627
0.015401400000001786
```

Comment: I stumbled on this answer ! I have a sorted dataframe and this is kind of what I was looking for . Is there an easy way to filter out based on minutes/hours? Lets say I want to get everything which happened at hour mark . So time is X:00:00 .

Comment: If I understand the question correctly that is dependent on the data. If it is very structured like the one in the question you can do something like df.loc[t1::288] (where t1 is the first mark and there are 288 5min intervals in a day.
If the data is not that structured it becomes harder, and maybe a binary-search style algorithm after a good guess can be beneficial. But in the case of very unstructured data it becomes harder and harder to gain much efficiency over the first answer.

Comment: Thanks ! I ended up doing something like df.opentime.dt.minute == 0